# Prisma generated code fails @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call and @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment ESLint rules

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, prisma

I have the ESLint rules [@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-assignment) and [@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-call) turned on and when I query the Prisma interface these rules fails.

Why do the generated models fail on these rules?

**Update: NVM, seems like it was a hickup in vs code. After a restart the error is gone..**

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider                       = "postgresql"
  url                                 = env("DATABASE_URL")
  shadowDatabaseUrl   = env("SHADOW_DATABASE_URL")
}

model Foo {
  bar String @id
}
```

```
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const data: Prisma.FooUncheckedCreateInput = {
    bar: 'hello',
 };

// Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.eslint[@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-assignment)
const args: Prisma.FooCreateArgs = {
  data,
 };

// Unsafe call of an `any` typed value.eslint[@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-call)
prisma.foo.create(args);
```

- OS: macOS
- Database: PostgreSQL
- Node.js version: 18

```
prisma                  : 5.4.2
@prisma/client          : 5.4.2
Current platform        : darwin-arm64
Query Engine (Node-API) : libquery-engine ac9d7041ed77bcc8a8dbd2ab6616b39013829574 (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/libquery_engine-darwin-arm64.dylib.node)
Schema Engine           : schema-engine-cli ac9d7041ed77bcc8a8dbd2ab6616b39013829574 (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/schema-engine-darwin-arm64)
Schema Wasm             : @prisma/prisma-schema-wasm 5.4.1-2.ac9d7041ed77bcc8a8dbd2ab6616b39013829574
Default Engines Hash    : ac9d7041ed77bcc8a8dbd2ab6616b39013829574
Studio                  : 0.494.0
```

Comment: Have you run `npx prisma generate`? this creates the type declaration files for you

Comment: I wouldn't generally lint generated code.

Comment: The types are generated and work fine. Somehow eslint doesnt fully understand the Prisma generated files and seem to believe that something i any in there somewhere...

Comment: I don't lint prismas code, I lint my code that calls prisma's code. For some reason eslint doesnt understand that the method I'm trying to call is not of type 'any'...

Answer (score 0):

NVM, seems like it was a hickup in vs code. After a restart the error is gone..

Comment: :facepalm:! fwiw, Command+Shift+P, "Restart ESLint Server", and "Restart TS Server" sometimes does the trick too, if restarting VS Code feels like a chore